# About using Fortran function in C with iso_c_binding

Tags: visual-c++, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I learn Fortran's C interoperability for a few days to call a Fortran function DLL from C.
Here I found this link:
[Use Fortran-code in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426677/use-fortran-code-in-c)

I try to create a Fortran DLL like this and my compiler is Intel Fortran compiler:

```
module integration
  implicit none

contains

  function Integrate(func, a,b, intsteps) result(integral)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: Integrate
    interface
      real function func(x)
        real, intent(in) :: x
      end function func
    end interface

    real :: integral, a, b
    integer :: intsteps
    intent(in) :: a, b, intsteps
    optional :: intsteps

    real :: x, dx
    integer :: i,n
    integer, parameter :: rk = kind(x)

    n = 1000
    if (present(intsteps)) n = intsteps

    dx = (b-a)/n

    integral = 0.0_rk
    do i = 1,n
      x = a + (1.0_rk * i - 0.5_rk) * dx
      integral = integral + func(x)
    end do

    integral = integral * dx
  end function

end module integration


    real(c_float) function wrapper_integrate(func, a, b, intsteps) result(integral) bind(C, name='integrate')
  use iso_c_binding
  use integration

 interface
    function iFunc(x) bind(C)
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      real(c_float) :: iFunc
      real(c_float), intent(in) :: x
    end function iFunc
  end interface

  type(C_FUNPTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: func
  real(c_float) :: a,b
  integer(c_int),intent(in) :: intsteps
  optional :: intsteps

  procedure(iFunc),pointer :: myfunc
  call c_f_procpointer(func, myfunc)

  if (present(intsteps)) then
    integral = Integrate(myfunc,a,b,intsteps)   <==error #8128
  else
    integral = Integrate(myfunc,a,b)          <==error #8128
  endif

end function wrapper_integrate
```

When I built the DLL, the error shows below

```
error #8128: The BIND attribute of the associated actual procedure differs from the BIND attribute of the dummy procedure.   [MYFUNC]
```

The error line denoted in code, it looks like `myfunc` is not equal to `func` defined in module integration. Maybe I can use the `iso_c_binding` to modify module `integration`.

Sometimes some Fortrans function have many arguments to be assigned and used in the function, it is not easy way to use `iso_c_binding` in Fortran. So how to solve the error in `MYFUNC`?

Comment: The dummy procedure in `Integrate` has the `bind` attribute; the function pointer `myfunc` which is the actual argument has interface given `iFunc` which hasn't the `bind` interface.

Comment: Yes! I forget it! Now I can export Fortran Dll.

Comment: And thank for your editing my question that make it neat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a dummy procedure has an explicit interface, then its characteristics must be the same as the characteristics of the actual procedure, except for some things not relevant here.

The characteristics of a procedure include whether it has the BIND attribute.

To make the characteristics consistent you can use a little intermediate procedure, that does not have BIND(C), to call your supplied BIND(C) procedure.

For example, with some other changes to avoid assumptions around whether c_float and c_int nominated default real and integer kinds:

```
function wrapper_integrate(func, a, b, intsteps)  &
    result(integral) bind(C, name='integrate')
  use iso_c_binding
  use integration
  implicit none

  interface
    function func(x) bind(C)
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      implicit none
      real(c_float), intent(in) :: x
      real(c_float) :: func
    end function func
  end interface

  real(c_float), intent(in) :: a,b
  integer(c_int), intent(in), optional :: intsteps
  real(c_float) :: integral

  real :: local_a, local_b
  integer :: local_intsteps

  local_a = a
  local_b = b
  if (present(intsteps)) then
    local_intsteps = intsteps
    integral = Integrate(local_func, a, b, local_intsteps)
  else
    integral = Integrate(local_func, a, b)
  end if
contains
  function local_func(x)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real :: local_func

    real(c_float) :: local_x

    local_x = x
    local_func = func(local_x)
  end function local_func
end function wrapper_integrate
```

Note that the presence of optional arguments in an interoperable procedure is a Fortran 2015 feature.

Comment: Thanks! I need to examine it!

Comment: By the way, Intel Fortran can be called in .NET Framework?

Comment: bind(C, name='integrate') should be bind(C, name='wrapper_integrate'), and it works! And this method is very helpful for me.

Comment: The name of the binding label depends on what you call the C function.

Comment: Well, If  I want to pass an array to local_func? How to do it?