# Calling Fortran package in C

Tags: visual-c++, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I reference [About using Fortran function in C with iso_c_binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763821/about-using-fortran-function-in-c-with-iso-c-binding/40767491#40767491) to write a intermediate program so that Odrpack95 (http://www.netlib.org/odrpack/) can be called in C. But I encounter some problems and need someone help.

### Fortran code

```
subroutine wrapper_ODR(FCN,N,M,NP,NQ,BETA,Y,X,&
        DELTA,WE,WD,IFIXB,IFIXX,JOB,NDIGIT,TAUFAC,&
        SSTOL,PARTOL,MAXIT,IPRINT,LUNERR,LUNRPT,&
     STPB,STPD,SCLB,SCLD,WORK,IWORK,INFO,LOWER,UPPER) bind(C, name='wrapper_ODR')
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: wrapper_ODR    
    use iso_c_binding
    use ODRPACK95
    implicit none


    interface 
        subroutine FCN(N,M,NP,NQ,LDN,LDM,LDNP,BETA,XPLUSD,IFIXB,IFIXX,LDIFX,&
        IDEVAL,F,FJACB,FJACD,ISTOP) bind(C)

        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none

        integer(c_int) :: IDEVAL,ISTOP,LDIFX,LDM,LDN,LDNP,M,N,NP,NQ

        real (c_double) :: BETA(1:NP),F(1:LDN,1:NQ),FJACB(1:LDN,1:LDNP,1:NQ), &
        FJACD(1:LDN,1:LDM,1:NQ),XPLUSD(1:LDN,1:M)

        integer(c_int) :: IFIXB(1:NP),IFIXX(1:LDIFX,1:M)

        end subroutine
    end interface


    integer(c_int) :: N,M,NP,NQ
    real(c_double) :: BETA(1:NP),Y(1:N,1:NQ),X(1:N,1:M)

!!!!!Optional
    integer(c_int), optional :: IFIXB(:),IFIXX(:,:),JOB,NDIGIT,MAXIT&
    ,IPRINT,LUNERR,LUNRPT,IWORK(:),INFO

    real(c_double),  optional :: DELTA(:,:),&
        WE(:,:,:),WD(:,:,:),TAUFAC,SSTOL,PARTOL,&
        STPB(:),STPD(:,:),SCLB(:),SCLD(:,:),&
         WORK(:),LOWER(:),UPPER(:)

    call ODR(inter_func,N,M,NP,NQ,BETA,Y,X)

contains 

    subroutine inter_func(N,M,NP,NQ,LDN,LDM,LDNP,BETA,XPLUSD,IFIXB,IFIXX,LDIFX,&
   IDEVAL,F,FJACB,FJACD,ISTOP)

        use REAL_PRECISION

       integer :: IDEVAL,ISTOP,LDIFX,LDM,LDN,LDNP,M,N,NP,NQ

       REAL (KIND=R8) :: BETA(1:NP),F(1:LDN,1:NQ),FJACB(1:LDN,1:LDNP,1:NQ), &
      FJACD(1:LDN,1:LDM,1:NQ),XPLUSD(1:LDN,1:M)
     INTEGER :: IFIXB(1:NP),IFIXX(1:LDIFX,1:M)


       integer(c_int) :: inter_IDEVAL,inter_ISTOP,inter_LDIFX,inter_LDM,&
           inter_LDN,inter_LDNP,inter_M,inter_N,inter_NP,inter_NQ

       real (c_double) :: inter_BETA(1:size(BETA)),inter_F(1:size(F,1),1:size(F,2)),&
           inter_FJACB(1:size(FJACB,1),1:size(FJACB,3),1:size(FJACB,3)),&
           inter_FJACD(1:size(FJACD,1),1:size(FJACD,2),1:size(FJACD,3)),inter_XPLUSD(1:size(XPLUSD,1),1:size(XPLUSD,2))

       integer(c_int) :: inter_IFIXB(1:size(IFIXB)),inter_IFIXX(1:size(IFIXX,1),1:size(IFIXX,2))

       inter_IDEVAL = IDEVAL
      inter_ISTOP = ISTOP
       inter_LDIFX = LDIFX
       inter_LDM = LDM
       inter_LDN = LDN
       inter_LDNP = LDNP
       inter_M = M
       inter_N = N
       inter_NP = NP
       inter_NQ = NQ

       !!!!REAL
       inter_BETA = BETA
       inter_F = F
       inter_FJACB = FJACB
       inter_FJACD = FJACD
      inter_XPLUSD = XPLUSD
       !!!!INTEGER[] 
       inter_IFIXB = IFIXB
       inter_IFIXX = IFIXX



   end subroutine inter_func
end subroutine wrapper_ODR
```

### C code

(I translated and modified from `simple_example.f90` inside ODRPACK95 )

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {

    void wrapper_ODR(void(*FCN)(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, \
        double [] ,double [1][4],int [], int [],int* ,\
        int*, double [1][4],double [1][2][4],double [] ,int* ),\

        int *N,int *M,int *NP,int *NQ,double BETA[],double Y[1][4],double X[1][4],\
        double DELTA[1][4],double WE[],double WD[],int IFIXB[],int IFIXX[],\
        int *JOB,int *NDIGIT,double *TAUFAC,double *SSTOL, double *PARTOL,\
        int *MAXIT, int *IPRINT, int *LUNERR, int *LUNRPT,double STPB[],\
        double STPD[], double SCLB[], double SCLD[], double WORK[], double IWORK[],\
        int *INFO, double LOWER[], double UPPER[]);

}
void FCN(int *N, int *M, int *NP, int *NQ, int *LDN, int *LDM, int *LDNP,\
    double BETA[], double XPLUSD[1][4], int IXIFB[], int IFIXX[],int *LDIFX,\
    int *IDEVAL, double F[1][4], double FJACB[1][2][4], double FJACD[],int *ISTOP){
// BETA[NP], XPLUSD[M][LDN], IXIFB[NP], IFIXX[M][LDIFX], F[NQ][LDN],  FJACB[NQ][LDNP][LDN], FJACD[NQ][LDM][LDN]
    *ISTOP =5;

    if (fmod(*IDEVAL,10.0)!=0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < *N; i++) {
            F[0][i] = BETA[0] * XPLUSD[0][i] + BETA[1];
        }

    }

}

int main(){
//X[M][N] Y[NQ][N],BETA[NP]
    int NP = 2, N = 4, M = 1, NQ = 1;
    double BETA[] = { 2.0, 0.5 };
    double X[1][4] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
    double Y[1][4] = { 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0 };



    wrapper_ODR(&FCN, &N, &M, &NP, &NQ, BETA, Y, X, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, \
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, \
        NULL, NULL);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Where `NP = 2`, `N = 4`,`M = 1`, `NQ = 1`, `LDN = 4`, `LDM = 1`, `LDNP = 2`,`LDIFX = 4`

### Problems

1. `ISTOP` is used for stopping regression procedure if `ISTOP` is not equal to 0. However when C code above is executed, no matter what `ISTOP` is, it continues regression procedure. It seems that `ISTOP` doesn't pass to `subroutine inter_func`.
2. In Fortran code, comment parts with `!` denote as passing array data parts. Well it doesn't ring any bell how to pass array data from C to Fortran or Fortran to C  by `inter_` variable.

### Updated

I modify C and Fortran code above, the result shown below:
[image: Result]
In C code, I set ISTOP = 5, but the result report shows it is 0.

Then if ODRPACK procedure succeeds, it should be like this:
[image]
And here is also Fortran code modified from `simple_example.f90`, It should be the same with C code:

```
PROGRAM ODRPACK95_EXAMPLE
   USE ODRPACK95
   USE REAL_PRECISION
   REAL (KIND=R8), ALLOCATABLE :: BETA(:),X(:,:),Y(:,:)
   INTEGER :: NP,N,M,NQ
   INTERFACE
      SUBROUTINE FCN(N,M,NP,NQ,LDN,LDM,LDNP,BETA,XPLUSD,IFIXB,IFIXX,LDIFX,&
         IDEVAL,F,FJACB,FJACD,ISTOP)
         USE REAL_PRECISION
         INTEGER :: IDEVAL,ISTOP,LDIFX,LDM,LDN,LDNP,M,N,NP,NQ
         REAL (KIND=R8) :: BETA(NP),F(LDN,NQ),FJACB(LDN,LDNP,NQ), &
            FJACD(LDN,LDM,NQ),XPLUSD(LDN,M)
         INTEGER :: IFIXB(NP),IFIXX(LDIFX,M)
      END SUBROUTINE FCN
   END INTERFACE

   NP = 2
   N  = 4
   M  = 1
   NQ = 1
   ALLOCATE(BETA(NP),X(N,M),Y(N,NQ))
   BETA(1:2) = (/ 2.0_R8, 0.5_R8 /)

   X(1:4,1)  = (/ 0_R8, 1_R8, 2_R8, 3_R8 /)
   Y(1:4,1)  = (/ 2_R8, 5_R8, 8_R8, 11_R8 /)
   CALL ODR(FCN,N,M,NP,NQ,BETA,Y,X)
   pause
END PROGRAM ODRPACK95_EXAMPLE


SUBROUTINE FCN(N,M,NP,NQ,LDN,LDM,LDNP,BETA,XPLUSD,IFIXB,IFIXX,LDIFX,&
   IDEVAL,F,FJACB,FJACD,ISTOP)

   USE REAL_PRECISION

   INTEGER :: IDEVAL,ISTOP,LDIFX,LDM,LDN,LDNP,M,N,NP,NQ, I
   REAL (KIND=R8) :: BETA(NP),F(LDN,NQ),FJACB(LDN,LDNP,NQ), &
      FJACD(LDN,LDM,NQ),XPLUSD(LDN,M)
   INTEGER :: IFIXB(NP),IFIXX(LDIFX,M)

   ISTOP = 0

    !Calculate model.
   IF (MOD(IDEVAL,10).NE.0) THEN
      DO I=1,N
         F(I,1) = BETA(1)*XPLUSD(I,1)+BETA(2)
      END DO
   END IF

END SUBROUTINE FCN
```

It seems that the variable value of C function `FCN` doesn't pass to wrapper_ODR, but I don't know where are my problems? Could someone help me?

Comment: I haven't spent much time looking at this, but in `wrapper_ODR` you have the dummy procedure `fcn`.  That isn't referenced in the subroutine at all.  Is that intended?

Comment: Sorry I don’t quite understand. What do you mean `fcn isn't referenced in the subroutine at all.`

Comment: You pass the function to the Fortran subroutine and in that subroutine give it an explicit interface (with the interface block).  But after that, there's no sign of it being used.  Instead, `inter_func` is sent along to `ODR` (which in turn has no mention of the original `fcn`).  I don't know about the flow of things in ODRPACK95, so I could easily be missing something.

Comment: Ok! When C passes variable data to wrapper_ODR and subroutine `FCN` receive data and  `inter_` variable are  assigned  by variable in  `FCN`

Comment: But I don't know how to assign to array in inter_func

Comment: You have the array assignment statements commented out.  (The allocate statements are not required - as written your inter_* array variables are automatic arrays).  Note that the interface of `inter_func` does not match that required by the ODRPACK95 docs.  You pass an array to a procedure as you would a scalar. Your C++ code has issues with its argument declarations.

Comment: Sorrt I am late to reply! In  `inter_func` , Would you indicate which parts don't match? Though I check ODRPACK95, I still cannot find. For C++ code, I use integer for declaring array size and to avoid ambiguity, I replace integer with integer variable.

Comment: And in `inter_func`, How to assign array to `inter_` aarray?

Comment: Okay! Actually, there is no need for `inter_func`, But I keep focusing with it. Now the code can work now.

Comment: Then I meet some problem again, How to deal with optional arguments?